# How to get the post parameters in before dispatch loop phalcon

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing, phalconeye

We can access post data in controller something like this:

```
$request = $this->di->get("request");
$data = $request->getJsonRawBody();
```

But is there any way to access POST data in services.php. I wanted to access it in an event:

```
if ($event->getType() == 'beforeDispatchLoop') { 
    $url = 'http://localhost/curl_logging/curlLogging.php'; 
    $router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router(); 
    $uri = $router->getRewriteUri(); 
    $controller = $dispatcher->getControllerName(); 
    $action = $dispatcher->getActionName(); 
    $params = array(); 
    $params['controller'] = $controller; 
    $params['action'] = $action; 
    calling_func($url, $params);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the portion of your services.php where you want to get the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way, you get your raw body:

```
if ($event->getType() == 'beforeDispatchLoop') {
    $request = $this->di->getRequest();
    // or
    // $request = $this->di->get('request');
    // $request = new \Phalcon\Http\Request();

    // straight from $_POST
    $user     = $request->getPost('login');

    // using filter for delivered data
    $email    = $request->getPost('email', 'email');

    // just obtaining full $_POST
    $form     = $request->getPost();
}
```

Further information available under [request documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/api/Phalcon_Http_Request.html).

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. But if the post data is in json format, i wanted to get the whole data. not a specific node like  mentioned 'email'.

Comment: @user1740757, Like you mentioned in your question: you can just use `$request->getJsonRawBody();` inside the `if`-statement.